# python nested dictionary with a strange fill behavior

Tags: python, dictionary

I saw a strange behavior in a Python 2.7.12 nested dict and I do not understand why it's happening. lets say that I have this dictionary:

```
list_1 = ['5', '10', '15', '30']
dict_1 = { i:[] for i in list_1 }
```

now I create a nested dict like this:

```
list_2 = ['a', 'b']
dict_2 = { i:dict_1 for i in list_2 }
```

and an other nested dict like this:

```
dict_3 = { i:{j:[] for j in list_1} for i in list_2 }
```

The dict_3 and dict_2 are identical if printed before I fill them:

```
{'a': {'15': [], '10': [], '30': [], '5': []}, 'b': {'15': [], '10': [], '30': [], '5': []}}
```

But when I fill the dictionaries like:

```
dict_2['a']['5'].append(1)
dict_3['a']['5'].append(1)
```

dict_2 has a behavior that I do not want, filling element '5' in both 'a' and 'b':

```
{'a': {'15': [], '10': [], '30': [], '5': [1]}, 'b': {'15': [], '10': [], '30': [], '5': [1]}}
```

dict_1 has the behavior that I want, filling only element '5' in 'a':

```
{'a': {'15': [], '10': [], '30': [], '5': [1]}, 'b': {'15': [], '10': [], '30': [], '5': []}}
```

I am guessing that in dict_2 the nested dict_1 is just a link to that dictionary, while dict_3 is a truly nested dictionary. Is that correct ? Anyhow I find this use of python dicts quite misleading, if it's not a bug, why is this behavior wanted in python ?

Comment: Why do you think this strange? `dict_2` contains two references to the same `dict_1`, while the `{}` comprehension creates a new dictionary every time it is invoked.

Comment: @dhke It *is* strange for people coming from languages where assignment can copy data.

Comment: @timgeb Point taken.

Comment: @dhke it felt strange because I was the last think I though about while debugging. What @ timgeb says is true, but as Python covers pointers it took a while to understand that I was doing a reference and not creating a new dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignment never copies data. It's just a little harder to see the assignment in a comprehension.

```
dict_2 = {i:dict_1 for i in list_2}
```

is equivalent to

```
dict_2 = {}
for i in list_2:
    dict_2[i] = dict_1 # the assignments I'm talking about
```

Now you have `dict_2[i]` be a reference to `dict_1` for all `i`. No data is copied. There's one dictionary with the value `{'15': [], '10': [], '30': [], '5': []}` in memory which happens to go by the name `dict_1` but is now also referenced by all the keys in `dict_2`. (You can have many names/references to the same value in memory.)

If you want actual deep copies of your dictionary, use

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> dict_2 = {i:deepcopy(dict_1) for i in list_2}
>>> dict_2['a']['5'].append(1)
>>> dict_2
{'a': {'10': [], '30': [], '15': [], '5': [1]}, 'b': {'10': [], '30': [], '15': [], '5': []}}
```

The same logic applies to `dict_3`.

Comment: This is much clearer now, I have done some more tests on lists and dicts and yes I did not understand that assignment were actually references. Anyhow it is still a bit misleading because of this:

`a = 0`;
`b = a`;

 `a=10`;

 `print a`;
 `print b`;

in this case the output would be 10 and 0, and this means there is a copy when there is an assignment !  I hope the code is readable.

Comment: @IanMartinPostuma no, in Python assignment NEVER copies data. It is really true. Always. This is what happens in your example: you bind the name `a` to the value `0`. Then you bind another name, `b` to literally the same object in memory. Then you *rebind* the name `a` to another value. This operation does not affect what the name `b` points to. No data was copied in the process.

Comment: so with my last example I have done the same as if i did `dict_2['b']={ i:[] for i in list_1 }`, in this way i rebind the `dict_2['b']` element to another value without rebinding the `dict_2['a']` element. Ok ! thanks a lot, I'll keep it in mind !